# Need ASP.Net/MVC Rich Text Editor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a "simple" RTE editor for a MVC application I'm programming.

The editor running the Stackoverflow message editor is almost exactly what I'm looking for.  We don't need anything as fancy as FCK's editor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the editor by Shield UI: http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/editor/basic-usage

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See this article - [10 jQuery and non-jQuery javascript Rich Text Editors](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors). Should be something there you like!

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow uses [WMD Editor](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/wmd/). When you say 'almost exactly what you're looking for', what other features are you after?

Comment: It has the formatting features I need, but I need it to be a fully WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: In that case I'd probably go for FCK then - as David points out you can strip out anything you don't need.

Answer (score 3):

I have personally used [**FCKEditor**](http://www.fckeditor.net/) on ASP.NET MVC with great success. An excellent editor, highly customisable. So as you don't need anything as complex as FCK with its defaults, you can strip it down to bare-bones.

Comment: There's also ckeditor - which is the next iteration of FckEditor -  http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 2):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) -- you can customize it to show as few or as many buttons as you want.

Comment: TinyMCE is very heavy. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik makes a decent set of .Net controls, including a WYSIWYG editor. Think you have to pay for the full version though...

[Telerik RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx)

Comment: Don't think .NET controls would be much use for MVC...

Comment: It may not be the *best* choice, but Telerik does support MVC.